# Triggering a task from a slider value change event not showing last value

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events

I am doing image processing, and so I am doing the processing on a secondary thread which looks like this:

```cs
namespace Project {
  public class Layer {
    private bool applyingActions = false;

    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; };

    public void ApplyActions() {
      if (applyingActions) return;
      applyingActions = true;

      Task.Run(() => {

        /* Do image processing here.... */

        Image = imageResult;

        applyingActions = false;

      });
    }

  }
}
```

I am triggering this thread with a [slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider?view=net-5.0) and the `ValueChanged` event like this:

```cs
namespace Project {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public Layer layer = new Layer();

    public BitmapImage DisplayImage { get { return layer.Image } };

    public MainWindow() {
      DataContext = this;
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs evt) {
      layer.ApplyActions();
    }
  }
}
```

The `xaml` looks something like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project">

  <Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Slider Value="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged"/>
    <Image x:Name="preview" Source="{Binding DisplayImage}" />
  </Grid>

</window>
```

The issue that I am facing is that the image doesn't reflect the value of the slider when the slider stops moving due to the fact that it is still processing the last step when the last `ValueChanged` event is fired.

I am looking for a way that will make the task process the last event and ignore events between the time the task started and the last event. What can be done to accomplish this?

I have tried using a cancellationtoken, however, it shows all the slider values...

```cs
namespace Project {
  public class Layer {
    private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; };

    public void ApplyActions() {
      cancelSource.Cancel();

      Task.Run(() => {

        /* Do image processing here.... */

        Image = imageResult;

      }, cancelSource.Token);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you experimented with using one of the other event handlers? For example, would `Drop` work?

Comment: You need to check the cancellation token frequently enough inside here: `/* Do image processing here.... */`. You can check it by calling its `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Okay, I have added in there, where would I request cancelation? Adding it before `Task.Run` never executes the task.

Comment: In the `ApplyActions` method the first thing you should do is to `Cancel` the previous `CancellationTokenSource`, and immediately after to create a new `CancellationTokenSource`, and store it in the `cancelSource` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do cache a value from slider and compare it at the end with handled value.

```
public class Layer {

    private double _processingValue = -1;
    private bool applyingActions = false;

    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; };

    public void ApplyActions(double value) 
    {
      _processingValue = value;
      if (applyingActions) return;
      applyingActions = true;

      Task.Run(() => {

        /* Do image processing here.... */

        Image = imageResult;

        applyingActions = false;
        
        if(value != _processingValue)
            ApplyActions(_processingValue);

      });
    }
}


private void OnValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
   layer.ApplyActions(e.NewValue);
}
```

Comment: You don't beleave it?! :))

Comment: Are you sure now, that it works, or still doubt? :)